# cakephp debug messages still displaying with debug set to 0 using ajax and json

Tags: cakephp

cakephp debug messages still displaying with debug set to 0 using ajax and json. I cannot set autorender to false, as I need to set the header to send json.

json.ctp

```
<?php
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate");
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header("X-JSON: ".$json);
echo $json;
?>
```

Controller

```
function index(){

        if (!empty($this->data)){

            // Handle all JSON requests here
            if ($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()){

                $domain = $this->data['domain'];

                        $results = $this->Domain->google_api($domain,$seo_action);

                $json = json_encode($results);

                $this->set(compact('json'));

                $this->render('json','ajax');

            } else {

                $domain = $this->data['Results']['domain'];

            }

        }

        $this->set(compact('domain'));

        $this->layout = 'front_end';
    }
```

app_controller

```
function beforeFilter(){

        if ($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) Configure::write('debug', 0);

    }
```

Comment: do you have any beforeFilter() in your controller that overrides the beforeFilter() from the app_controller ?

Comment: Where's your debug()?  paste code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the `Configure::write('debug', 0);` as first line to your `json.ctp`. so that it will:

```
<?php
  Configure::write('debug', 0);
  header("Pragma: no-cache");
  header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate");
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  header("X-JSON: ".$json);
  echo $json;
?>
```